# How to use if in a list (Python)

Tags: python

I am working on a gacha game based on anime charcaters.

I have a listed defined as the following

```
player_team = [
    f'{Fore.WHITE}Academy Naruto{Style.RESET_ALL} [1 star]',
    f'{Fore.WHITE}1% Deku{Style.RESET_ALL} [1 star]',
    f'{Fore.WHITE}Academy Sakura{Style.RESET_ALL} [1 star]'
]
```

I want the game to display the list of anime characters the player has.

When the player uses the command that shows the player list of his/her charcaters, I want the ones in team to show up too but with "(In team)" next to them so the way player knows which one is being used on the team when the player has multiple copies of that hero

I made a list called

```
player_heroes = [

]
```

But I have no idea what I should code in there.

Let us say that the player only has Naruto, Deku, Sakura that are inside the list

```
player_team
```

I want to code

```
player_heroes
```

as

```
player_heroes = [
    everything inside player_team, but with "(in team)" next to them
]
```

For that I thought I might have to use a if inside the list so that is why I named this question "How to use if in a list (Python)" Thank you for reading this, have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension

```
player_heroes = [f'{team} (in team)' for team in player_team]
```

Comment: This is called list comprehension, not in-line for loop. They are different

Answer (score 0):

You can absolutely have an `if` statement in a list.

The syntax is:

```
In [1]: a = [1, 2, 3, 4]                                                                             
In [2]: [i for i in a if i % 2 == 0]                                                                 
Out[2]: [2, 4]
```

This is called a list comprehension, you can look up this term for further information.